# Cloud disk appeared: how to remove?

Tags: windows, cloud

Good afternoon!
I have encountered the following situation: I don't understand why, but a strange cloud disk appeared in the list of disks - cDrive(X:) (screenshot attached). The operating system is Windows 7.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqQG8.png)

The disk itself can not be unmounted or deleted either simply or with Unlocker - it pops up a message about the impossibility of the operation.

The first thing I did was to check the properties of the disk - previously the file system of the disk was specified COSFS and the disk volume was counted in EB (exabytes), but after disconnecting the connection to the network everything became zero - screenshot attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvJsW.jpg)

How do I delete this disk? I looked in disk management - there is no disk there at all.
Maybe someone who has faced this problem - please tell me how to solve it (or tell me where to write).